# Convert Docx4J to .Net library by using ikvmc

Tags: ikvm, docx4j

The downloaded package from Docx4j with all dependencies contains dozens of jar files. I think  `docx4j-2.8.1.jar` depends on all of them.

What is the syntax I should use to convert `docx4j-2.8.1.jar` and all its dependencies to .Net assemblies?

Comment: This question is relevant again since docx4j is now on 3.3 and docx4j.Net is on 3.2 and not changed in 2 years.  3.3 has majot PDF output changes.

Answer (score 0):

Answered at your [crosspost in the docx4j forum](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/convert-docx4j-2-8-1-to-net-assemblies-by-using-ikvm-t1573.html).

Comment: Please see my reply there. Thanks.